# Oracle multi value parameter error

Tags: reporting-services, multivalue

I am using below query in SSRS 2008 and I am getting an error when I click the 'Next' button on the ***Design Query*** window in ***Report Wizard***.

"An error occurred while the query design method was being saved. ORA-00911: invalid character"

```
  SELECT E.EMPID, E.NAME
    FROM EMP E
   WHERE E.EMPID IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(CAST(SPLIT(:I_IDS) AS TEMP_TBL)));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry guys! Its was semi colon at the end.. that caused this error.. very sorry !!

Comment: This has tripped me up before too. While the semi-colon is technically required in Oracle (even though various query tools let you omit it) it causes an error in SSRS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simplifying your WHERE clause to use the condition:

```
WHERE E.EMPID IN (:I_IDS);
```

- in your query? (This won't work for multiple values in a normal SQL client, but *does* in SSRS datasets, in my experience.)